# How can I check class (not object) inheritance?

Tags: php, inheritance

For example:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}
```

Are there any function like `is_a('B', 'A')` to check not object, but class inheritance? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. You were almost right: Here is the link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: Yes, sorry and thanks. I didn't pay attention to the third argument :(